# Create GUI in JHipster

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, yeoman, yeoman-generator, jhipster

Is there a tutorial or something where i can learn how to create the Frontend-Part for a JHipster-Application from scratch?
For me it's very complex with all the files - and the building tools.

For example I don't want the complete admin-interface. But when i delete the  includes in the index.html a grunt-build wont work anymore.

```
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Warning: Different sources attempting to write to the same destination:
...
```

So is there a best practice or something how to get started creating a new Interface for JHipster-Projects?

Comment: I think you shouldnt delete the includes from index.html as gulp populates it automatically. Just delete the files you don't need and when you compile it they wont be added to index.html